# Push notifications in Progressive web app through GCM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

while sending push notification i got ( Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: require is not defined(…)) error.here is my code

```
 const endPoint = subscription.endpoint.slice(subscription.endpoint.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
console.log(endPoint);
var gcm = require('node-gcm');
var message = new gcm.Message({
    notification: {
        title: "Hello, World",
        icon: "ic_launcher",
        body: "This is a notification that will be displayed ASAP.",
        tag:"hello"
    }
});

var regTokens = [endPoint];
  var sender = new gcm.Sender('AIzaSyD9Bcxd_MQZFoGjO1y_hPm-xUdgnM25Ny4'); //API Key
  // Now the sender can be used to send messages
  sender.send(message, { registrationTokens: regTokens }, function (error, response) {
   if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(400);
    }
   else {
      console.log(response);
      res.status(200);
    }
  });
      })
    })
}
```

Screenshot of error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Cmqd.jpg)

Comment: You cannot use `require` in browser. If you are into hybrid app development, you need to install the plugin PushNotification and then you can further check the docs here `https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send push notifications thorugh GCM in progessive web apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660508/send-push-notifications-thorugh-gcm-in-progessive-web-apps)

Answer (score 2):

This code uses `require`, so it looks to me like you're trying to use node code in the browser. To do that you'll need to use something like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), although I'm not sure that's going to work for `node-gcm` as it may have certain requirements about sending network requests without cross origin restrictions etc.